# AFNetworking - cancel image download

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, afnetworking

How to cancel image download which are in queue,

I am using AFNetworking for image cache, now at one point i need to cancel download images, I am not getting any function for cancel download.

In SDWebImage I was using below function, is there any similar function in AFNetworking.

```
[self.imgView cancelCurrentImageLoad];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
[self.imgView cancelImageRequestOperation];
```